# How to hide Promotions in Oracle ATG business control center without deleting them from the dcs_promotion table

Tags: atg

How to hide **Promotions** in Oracle **ATG business control center** without deleting them from the **dcs_promotion table**. Do we have some **property** where we can change it and  make specific promotions unsearchable in business control center? I can not find anything yet where we can hide the promotions without **deleting** them. Need Help!
I'm new to ATG

Answer (score 0):

The BCC allows [access rights](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69533_01/Platform.11-3/ATGBCCAdminGuide/html/s0403settingaccessrightsinthebusiness01.html) to be configured for all parts.  I would recommend setting up folders in the BCC and restrict access to the folders.  Below is an example of the access rights you can set:

[image]

Comment: I found the **version_deleted** property in **dcs_promotion** table and updated it to 1 from 0. After updating the property of specific promotions and committing the changes, those specific promotions were no longer searchable in   **business control center**

Comment: Seems like a hack, why not just move to a folder that only admins have access to? I guess if it works ...